# Pass Rails model params to javascript onchange call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Say I have the following rails code in a view:

```
    <%= form.select(:language_id,
        options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, :id, :name),
        {},
        { :onchange => "setThemeAndMode('theme', 'mode')", class: "form-control" })
    %>
```

Is it possible to send, say `language.theme` and `language.mode` to the `setThemeAndMode` call in the onchange event? Or even the specific `language` model element as some flat json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Rails's document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), you can pass the block to `select` for customizing how the options tags will be rendered.

```
form.select :language_id do
  Language.all.each do |lang|
    content_tag(:option, c.name, value: c.id,
      onchange: "setThemeAndMode('#{get_theme_logic}', '#{get_mode_logic}')")
  end
end
```

You also can define a helper for rendering the `content_tag` to make your code cleaner

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out when I'm home later. I chose the options_from_* for brevity, but looks like this tripped me up in the long run. So `get_theme_logic` in this instance, can be `language.theme`?

Comment: @LokiSinclair Of course it is possible if your `language` object already had `theme` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time following what you want, but here's a shot at what I think you're asking.

You can interpolate the onchange string if you know the values at render time.

```
<%= form.select(:language_id,
    options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, :id, :name),
    {},
    { :onchange => "setThemeAndMode('#{Mything}', '#{other thing}')", class: "form-control" })
%>
```

If you're trying to get the value of the select element's newly changed value, you'll need to get the select element's values in the javascript.

```
function setThemeAndModel() {
  var value = document.querySelector('input[name="language_id"').value
}
```